# Is there any way to prevent page load of images with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, browser

I'd like to build a lazy loading plugin. Some resources have indicated that as soon as a src is defined on an image, the browser begins to load it. At what point in page processing does this happen? Is it possible to code in some javascript that prevents this from happening?

Comment: Don't set the source.

Comment: use data-src see the lazy loading of other plugins, Owl Carousel is an example

Comment: As soon as the `src` attribute is set, the browser will begin sending out HTTP requests and there is no way to stop it. The only thing you can do is don't set the source at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly that you do not want to load an image until the user interacts somehow, this is what you might be looking for.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z2kgpL37/

```
<img id="myImg" src="" width="107" height="98">


<button onclick="myFunction()">Load image</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myImg").src = "http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/compman.gif";
}
</script>
```

If this helped, accept the answer :)

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to do this without modifying markup, but it looks like this is impossible?

Comment: @mikeyla85 absolutely no way, And if this helped be sure to accept this answer :)